# Fill image with color by mask

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I have an origin vehicle image and what I need to implement is fill this with different colors:
http://image.openlan.ru/images/25842748100117640420.png

I've tried to reach it using code below:

```
- (UIImage *) coloredImageWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDarken);
    CGRect rect = (CGRect){ CGPointZero, self.size };
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, self.CGImage);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage);

    [color set];
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    // wheel
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:(CGRect){ 700, 200, 200, 200 }];
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
    [path fill];

    UIImage *coloredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return coloredImage;
}
```

And of course it's not what I expected:

http://image.openlan.ru/images/05312201634158625573.png

Currently I've encountered with two problems. First of all I'd like to figure out how to reveal filled background in some area like wheels, as instance. And the second one is how to create the most similar colored vehicle images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your going to want to do most of this in Photoshop. You need a base image that is transparent in the places that you want to show through. Then you want to create a mask image that shows where you want color (using alpha to indicate how much tint to use). Then you'll mask the image and draw it on your background.

I assume a PhotoShop file with a layer mask was used to create the tinted vehicles in your initial example. You'll want those two layers (the base layer and the mask) as separate PNG files. Whoever created the original Photoshop file should be able to provide those.

Trying to do this programmatically from a single, flat image is unlikely to give you the kind of results you'd want.